# pass the user prop obtained from useQuery within a protected route to its child components

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, react-query

I'm trying to pass the user object from the protected route into children to use it in the child components, how can i obtain that?
**"note that useGetCurrentUser is returning the user object"**

app.jsx

```
<Route
 path="/"
 element={
 <ProtectedRouteAdmin>
     <AdminLayout project={false} />
 </ProtectedRouteAdmin>
 }
>
```

ProtectedRouteAdmin.jsx

```
import { useGetCurrentUser } from "../../api/useAuth";

export const ProtectedRouteAdmin = ({ children }) => {
  const { data: user, isLoading, isError } = useGetCurrentUser();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  console.log(isError);
  if (isError) {
    navigate("/login");
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!user && !isLoading) {
      navigate("/login");
    } else if (user && user.isAdmin === false && !isLoading) {
      navigate("/dashboard");
    }
  }, [user, navigate]);

  return children;
};

export default ProtectedRouteAdmin;
```

AdminLayout.jsx

```
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

const AdminLayout = () => {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <main className="dashboard">
        <SmallSideBar links={adminLinks} />
        <BigSidebar links={adminLinks} />
        <div>
          <Navbar />
          <div className="dashboard-page">
            <Outlet />
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};

export default AdminLayout;
```

Comment: Do you need to even pass the user object down as props? Why not use the `useGetCurrentUser` hook again in downstream components so they can access the cached user data?

Comment: that's true it's working rn

Comment: it's resolved, i have another question i will open new post for that :)

Answer (score 1):

solved by using useGetCurrentUser hook inside AdminLayout too !